# RadioBoxes aren't being submitted after changing their `checked` status using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form with multiple radioboxes that I change their `checked` status depending on the user interaction.

When I load the page and submit it without changing anything, the POST request carries the value of the checked radiobox, however when I change the status using JQuery after a certain user behavior the changed radiobox's value isn't being submitted.

```
<input checked="checked" name="resident" type="radio" value="no">
<input name="resident" type="radio" value="yes">
```

I am using the following function to change the status:

```
$('[data-toggle="section-radio"]').click(function(){
    section = $(this).closest('.tab-pane');
    section.find('[data-toggle="section-radio"]').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $(section).find('[type="radio"]').removeAttr('checked');
    $(this).find('[type="radio"]').attr('checked','true');
});
```

After doing that the radioboxes change as following:

```
<input name="resident" type="radio" value="no">
<input name="resident" type="radio" value="yes" checked="checked">
```

Do I have to refresh the DOM or should I change the `checked` value in another way?

**EDIT**

I am using a normal submit button:

```
<input type='submit' class='btn btn-finish btn-fill btn-warning btn-wd btn-sm' name='finish' value='save' />
```

Comment: How are you submitting the form? Can you post the rest of the <form> element?

Comment: I am just using a normal submit button, I edited the question.

Comment: add `.attr('checked',true)` is a boolean no a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using prop instead of attr.  Attr refers to the default value whereas prop refers to the current value.

See:  http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Also, you need just need to set it to false if you want it un-checked.

so your code would look like this:

```
$('[data-toggle="section-radio"]').click(function(){
    section = $(this).closest('.tab-pane');
    section.find('[data-toggle="section-radio"]').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $(section).find('[type="radio"]').prop('checked', false);
    $(this).find('[type="radio"]').prop('checked', true);
});
```